# Single functions.php or split into many small files?

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development

I am creating a simple framework with theme options. I have divided chunks of code within `functions.php` and placed it within a specific folder structure.

Now in my main `functions.php` file, I only have `require_once` calls to these files.

But for the sake of argument - let's say that I'll end up with 20 files to include.

#### QUESTIONS:

1. Does this have effect on WP performance in a visible way ?
2. Is it better to keep it all within 1 file (functions.php)
3. what is the best way to go about this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> **1.** Does this have effect on WP performance in a visible way ?

*IF* it would have a real affect for some small files, then it would have an affect that has an impact lower than WP: PHP and server performance. Does it really have an affect? Not really. But you can still simply start doing performance tests yourself.

> **2.** Is it better to keep it all within 1 file (functions.php)

Now the question is "What is better"? From overall file(s) loading time? From file organisation point of view? Anyway, it doesn't make any difference. Do it in a way so you don't loose overview and can maintain the result in a way that is pleasant for you.

> **3.** what is the best way to go about this?

What I normally do is simply hooking somewhere in (`plugins_loaded`, `after_setup_theme`, etc. - depends on what you need) and then just require them all:

```
foreach ( glob( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) ) as $file )
    require_once $file;
```

Anyway, you can make it a little more complicated and flexible as well. Take a look at that example:

```
<?php

namespace WCM;

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) OR exit;

class FilesLoader implements \IteratorAggregate
{
    private $path = '';

    private $files = array();

    public function __construct( $path )
    {
        $this->setPath( $path );
        $this->setFiles();
    }

    public function setPath( $path )
    {
        if ( empty( $this->path ) )
            $this->path = \plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ).$path;
    }

    public function setFiles()
    {
        return $this->files = glob( "{$this->getPath()}/*.php" );
    }

    public function getPath()
    {
        return $this->path;
    }

    public function getFiles()
    {
        return $this->files;
    }

    public function getIterator()
    {
        $iterator = new \ArrayIterator( $this->getFiles() );
        return $iterator;
    }

    public function loadFile( $file )
    {
        include_once $file;
    }
}
```

It's a class that does basically the same (needs PHP 5.3+). The benefit is that it's a bit more fine grained, so you can easily just load files from folders that you need to perform a specific task:

```
$fileLoader = new WCM\FilesLoader( 'assets/php' );

foreach ( $fileLoader as $file )
    $fileLoader->loadFile( $file );
```

### Update

As we live in a new, post PHP v5.2 world, we can make use of the `\FilterIterator`. Example of the shortest variant:

```
$files = new \FilesystemIterator( __DIR__.'/src', \FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS );
foreach ( $files as $file )
{
    /** @noinspection PhpIncludeInspection */
    ! $files->isDir() and include $files->getRealPath();
}
```

If you have to stick with PHP v5.2, then you still can go with the `\DirectoryIterator` and pretty much the same code.

Comment: cool. Thank you for the explanation :)

checking for files in a specific folder probably won't help with what I'm doing, although it's a nice idea.

I'm trying to make a framework which is Modular. So all "modules" would be in separate files which would be listed as separate entries (require_once) in the functions.php. That way if someone doesn't want to include one of the modules (for example: theme-customizer) - then can just comment that out etc. That's the plan anyways :) Thanks again.

Comment: @MegaMan You could as well filter the output before calling `loadFile()` or `require_once`. So simply offer something like theme support where the user himself can use [`add_theme_support()/remove_*()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_theme_support) to only take the modules he wants. Then simply use the result for `$loadFile()` or `glob()`. Btw, if this was your solution, please mark it as such. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I reworked @kaiser answer a bit to my needs - thought I share it. I wanted more options, those are explained inside the code and at the usage example below.

**Code:**

```
<?php

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) OR exit;

/**
 * Functions_File_Loader
 * 
 * Makes it possible to clutter the functions.php into single files.
 * 
 * @author kaiser
 * @author ialocin
 * @link http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/111970/22534
 *
 */

class Functions_File_Loader implements IteratorAggregate {

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    private $parameter = array();

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $path;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $pattern;

    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $flags;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    private $files = array();

    /**
     * __construct
     *
     * @access public 
     * @param array $parameter
     */
    public function __construct( $parameter ) {
        $this->set_parameter( $parameter );
        $this->set_path( $this->parameter[ 'path' ] );
        $this->set_pattern( $this->parameter[ 'pattern' ] );
        $this->set_flags( $this->parameter[ 'flags' ] );
        $this->set_files();
    }

    /**
     * set_parameter
     *
     * @access public 
     * @param array $parameter
     */
    public function set_parameter( $parameter ) {
        if ( empty( $parameter ) )
            $this->parameter = array('','','');
        else
            $this->parameter = $parameter;
    }

    /**
     * get_parameter
     *
     * @access public 
     * @return array
     */
    public function get_parameter() {
        return $this->parameter;
    }

    /**
     * set_path
     *
     * defaults to get_stylesheet_directory()
     * 
     * @access public 
     * @param string $path
     */
    public function set_path( $path ) {
        if ( empty( $path ) )
            $this->path = get_stylesheet_directory().'/';
        else
            $this->path = get_stylesheet_directory().'/'.$path.'/';
    }

    /**
     * get_path
     *
     * @access public 
     * @return string
     */
    public function get_path() {
        return $this->path;
    }

    /**
     * set_pattern
     *
     * defaults to path plus asterisk »*«
     * 
     * @access public 
     * @param string $pattern
     */
    public function set_pattern( $pattern ) {
        if ( empty( $pattern ) )
            $this->pattern = $this->get_path() . '*';
        else
            $this->pattern = $this->get_path() . $pattern;
    }

    /**
     * get_pattern
     *
     * @access public 
     * @return string
     */
    public function get_pattern() {
        return $this->pattern;
    }

    /**
     * set_flags
     *
     * @access public 
     * @param integer $flags
     */
    public function set_flags( $flags ) {
        if ( empty( $flags ) )
            $this->flags = '0';
        else
            $this->flags = $flags;
    }

    /**
     * get_flags
     *
     * @access public 
     * @return integer
     */
    public function get_flags() {
        return $this->flags;
    }


    /**
     * set_files
     *
     * @access public 
     */
    public function set_files() {
        $pattern = $this->get_pattern();
        $flags = $this->get_flags();
        $files = glob( $pattern, $flags );
        $this->files = $files;
    }


    /**
     * get_files
     *
     * @access public 
     * @return array
     */
    public function get_files() {
        return $this->files;
    }

    /**
     * getIterator
     * 
     * This function name has to be kept
     * 
     * @access public 
     * @return void
     */
    public function getIterator() {
        $iterator = new ArrayIterator( $this->get_files() );
        return $iterator;
    }

    /**
     * load_file
     *
     * @access public 
     * @param string $file
     */
    public function load_file( $file ) {
        include_once $file;
    }
}
```

**Usage example:**

```
$parameter = array(
        // define path relative to get_stylesheet_directory()
        // optional, defaults to get_stylesheet_directory()
        'path' => 'includes/plugins',
        // optional, defaults to asterisk »*«
        // matches all files ending with ».php« 
        // and not beginning with »_«, good for quickly deactivating 
        // directories searched are »path« and »subfolders«
        // Additional examples:
        // '{*/,}{[!_],}func-*.php' same as above but for files with a prefix
        // '[!_]*.php' php files in defined »path«, not beginning with »_« 
        'pattern' => '{*/,}[!_]*.php',
        // optional, defaults to 0
        // needed if for example brackets are used
        // more information: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php
        'flags' => GLOB_BRACE
    );
// create object
$functionsfileloader = new Functions_File_Loader( $parameter );
// load the files
foreach ( $functionsfileloader as $file ) {
    $functionsfileloader->load_file( $file );
}
```